# FileMaker Server and account password expiration date

Tags: php, passwords, filemaker

I have done a web application with php that use FileMaker Server and require authentication to login.

The authentication use the account created in FileMaker.
All the accounts have a password that expire in 90 days.

All the user can change the password via browser but the trouble is that if the user password is expired it seem that FileMaker does't allow the user to change the password himself.

Is there a way to know the **password expiration date** before reach the expiration?

I have tried for a lot of time and up to now I have not still found null to care.

Answer (score 0):

No built in function for this, no. I would recommend that you maintain a users table in your FileMaker solution where you can add a field for expiration date and handle the password changes via scripting, thereby logging the expiry date yourself. (Current date + 89 on change of password, in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to retrieve a number of days before password expiration, but here is what I would do.

```
$fm = new FileMaker();
$fm->setProperty ('database', 'fileName');
$fm->setProperty ('hostspec', 'hostName');
$fm->setProperty ('username', 'userName');
$fm->setProperty ('password', 'userPassword');

$result = $fm->listLayouts();
if(FileMaker::isError($result)) {
   if ($result->getCode() == '211'){
       echo "password has expired";
       // FM Error 211 - Password has expired
       // inform user that their password has expired 
       //and guide them through updating their password 
       }
}
```